# Exchange the double infinite sum order

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I am trying to exchange the order of a double summation, but I think I've failed on doing it. The sum and my result is

$\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{m=r}^\infty=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{r=0}^m$

I obtained this drawing a triangle and seeing the behavior of the indices, 
but I'm almost sure that there is an error, since the main result of the whole equation is not satisfactory. So I would be really grateful if some could help me to find the way to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the right hand side there isn't an $n$ so that you're allowing values of $r$ bigger than $n$. This doesn't happen on the left hand side. Instead, for fixed $m$ on the right hand side, you should get values of $r$ between $0$ and $\min\{m,n\}$.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I have to split the two sums in the left to four sums in the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rhys suggested. The way of change the order of the double sum is taking into account that we are performing a summation over an infinite triangle $0 \leq r \leq m $. So the double sum turns into

$\sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{m=r}^\infty = \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{r=0}^m + \sum_{m=n+1}^\infty \sum_{r=0}^n $